# Pandas - `loc` returns empty DataFrame on all but one column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm trying to access some rows based on column values. I read a CSV with

```py
df = pd.read_csv("edges.txt", dtype=str)
```

which creates the following DataFrame:

```
        TripId          MatchId   StartHour   Source      Destination
0       20120401017000  0         7           28819367    52408159
1       20120401017000  0         7           52408159    62804102
2       20120401017000  0         7           62804102    65398897
3       20120401017000  0         7           65398897    65398897
4       20120401017000  0         7           74066894    77482478
...     ...             ...       ...         ...         ...
62014   20120430097008  1         18          78141321    88912706
62015   20120430097008  1         18          88912706    218287467
62016   20120430097008  1         18          218287467   236637429
62017   20120430097008  1         18          236637429   245325123
62018   20120430097008  1         18          245325123   245374827
```

When I access a trip with a specific ID, it works fine:

```py
df.loc[df["TripId"] == "20120401017000"]
```

```
      TripId            MatchId   StartHour  Source      Destination
0     20120401017000    0         7          28819367    52408159
1     20120401017000    0         7          52408159    62804102
2     20120401017000    0         7          62804102    65398897
3     20120401017000    0         7          65398897    74066894
4     20120401017000    0         7          74066894    77482478
...   ...               ...       ...        ...         ...
86    20120401017000    2         7          330994406   484314696
87    20120401017000    2         7          484314696   502572843
88    20120401017000    2         7          502572843   758286629
89    20120401017000    2         7          758286629   791164312
90    20120401017000    2         7          791164312   974728472
```

However, when I try to access rows with a specific `MatchId`, it returns an empty DataFrame:

```py
df.loc[df["MatchId"] == "2"]
```

```
TripId  MatchId  StartHour  Source  Destination
```

Same for every column except for `TripId`:

```py
df.loc[df["Source"] == "283782532"]
```

```
TripId  MatchId  StartHour  Source  Destination
```

I'm a bit confused about this. `TripId` is not an index, and it doesn't seem special in any way. I make sure that every value is a string:

```py
df.dtypes
```

```
TripId         object
MatchId        object
StartHour      object
Source         object
Destination    object
dtype: object
```

I'm a bit confused why every column but `TripId` returns an empty DataFrame. `TripId` is not an index, and it doesn't seem special in any way.
How can I access rows with specific values for columns other than `TripId`?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example?

Comment: Did you try for example **df.loc[df.loc[:, "MatchId"] == "2"]**?

Comment: That should work. Can you show us the first couple rows of your "edges.txt" file?

Comment: @Hongpei I tried to reproduce by copying the first few rows of the big DataFrame as well as creating an equal one from scratch. It worked for the one I created, and not the copy of the large one, with everything being equal - or so I thought. Thanks to julian, I noticed that Jupyter Notebook doesn't show whitespace for tables, and that was the problem. Thank you for your comment, also to Jan Pansky and Riaz!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle your command should work as it does for df["TripId"]. Did you check for leading/trailing white spaces?

```
any(char.isspace() for char in df.iloc[0][1])
```

Comment: There it is! Tables in Jupyter Notebook don't show whitespace, and so I didn't realise that they were there anyway! Thank you!!!